# .Net application memory consumption is increasing in Edge

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks, microsoft-edge, jqxgrid

I opened my web application in Edge. When I login through the application and come to the homepage I noted the memory consumption of the application in task manager. Then I performed some operations on the site and again go the task manager and see that the memory is increasing in an unexpected way; up to 1800 MB.

What things causes the leak of memory on client side?

I used JQX, Google maps API and jQuery on my client side. Does anyone have any idea what causes releasing this memory?

[image]

Comment: Please be aware that 'IE' and 'Edge' are different browsers. We can see from the screenshot of the task manager that you specifically mean Edge in this case. However to solve this we need to see your code.

Comment: How much memory is Edge using when you open it without doing anything else? Do you have some extensions loaded in to it? Generally speaking memory leaks occur when DOM elements are removed but not released from memory. This is normally handled by the browser themselves, and each one is a matter of bytes, so to use several Gb of memory so quickly is highly unlikely.

Comment: when I opened my application first time then edge is consuming the 450 MB approximately then i performed some operations like opening and closing of popups and again after come to the task manager then again it increasing up-to 600 and when I opened the application for almost half n hour and doing nothing then it reaching the level up-to 1800 MB

Comment: Without seeing your code or knowing what it does it's very hard to diagnose the issue. As I stated above, though, garbage collection is handled by the browser. If this behaviour is not happening in other browsers then it's likely just another reason why Edge is a terrible browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [windbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) to detect the memory leak. More details tutorials, you could check [Memory Leak Detection Using Windbg](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg) and 
 [identify Memory Leak With Process Explorer And Windbg](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alikl/2009/02/15/identifying-memory-leak-with-process-explorer-and-windbg/).